# How to implement GetMany method from IVector interface

Tags: windows-store-apps, c++-cx

I've tried to create custom implementation of ICollectionView but my app hasn't passed the certification. The reason is that WACK tool states that signature of GetMany method does not match signature of GetMany in windows.winmd

Here is what windows.winmd says about GetMany:

```
unsigned int GetMany(unsigned int startIndex, [Windows::Foundation::Metadata::LengthIsAttribute] Platform::Array<T>^ items)
```

However, according to compiler's hint, I've defined GetMany method this way:

```
virtual unsigned int GetMany(unsigned int index, Platform::WriteOnlyArray<Platform::Object^>^ items);
```

It compiles and works fine but WACK complains about it. I also found that Array as an out parameter mey be implemented this way:

```
virtual unsigned int GetMany(unsigned int index, Platform::Array<Platform::Object^>^* items);
```

However, in that case compiler said that my class is abstract and it misses implementation of GetMany method. I even tried implementing both methods but that crushes compiler.

I can go with workaround and implement feature different way (without ICollectionView) however, from design perspective this solution fits me the best.

Comment: This has to be a WACK bug, I'm pretty sure that IVector::GetMany() uses the [FillArray pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh700131.aspx) so WriteOnlyArray is correct.  Other code I google also uses it.  Update your question with the exact WACK error message, consider filing a bug report at connect.microsoft.com

Comment: I have the message in polish, so it's rather useless. Since MS started to translate its developer tools we, non native English speakers, have problems with googling solutions to issues. I'll try with connect.microsoft.com

Answer (score 0):

It may be instructive to look at collection.h in your installation (which defines Platform::VectorView's implementation). It defines the GetMany function as:

```
virtual unsigned int GetMany(unsigned int startIndex, WriteOnlyArray<T>^ dest)
```

So you are correct in wanting to use `WriteOnlyArray`. Is your collection templated on type `Object^`?

Well-hidden but informative MSDN topic on different WinRT array patterns and their uses: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700131.aspx